# Number theory problem based on remainder

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the remainder when $(128)^{(128)^{128}}$ is divided by 7.

My attempt:

Remainder is $(128 \mod 7)^{(128 \mod 7)^{128\mod 7}}=(2)^{(2)^{2}}=16 \mod 7=2$.Is my answer and method of solving correct?

Comment: The exponent mods are not the correct method.

Comment: @abiessu,then what is the correct method,Sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can see that $128^{3}\equiv 1\mod 7)$ (you can check this by hand). Now, this implies $128^{n}\equiv 128^{n\mod 3}\mod 7$. To check what $128^{128}\mod 3$ is, we note that $128^{2}\equiv 1\mod 7$, so this implies $128^{n}\equiv 128^{n\mod 2}\mod 3$ Therefore, the number you are looking for is $128^{128^{128}}\mod 7\equiv 128^{128^{128}\mod 3}\mod 7\equiv 128^{128^{128\mod 2}\mod 3}\mod 7\equiv 128^{128^{0}\mod 3}\mod 7\equiv 128^{1}\mod 7\equiv 128\mod 7\equiv 2$.

The answer you got is correct, but your method is actually incorrect: $5^3\mod 3$ by your method would give $(5\mod 3)^{3\mod 3}\mod 3\equiv 2^{0}\mod 3\equiv 1$, while you can easily check the answer is 2.

Answer (score 2):

From Fermat's Little Theorem
$$
2^6\equiv 1\pmod 7,\enspace 2^7\equiv 2\pmod 7
$$
$128=2^7$; so,
$$
128^{128^{128}}\equiv 2^{128^{128}}\pmod 7.
$$
Now we should find remainder of $128^{128}$:
$$
128^{128}\equiv ? \pmod 6
$$
(because $2^6\equiv 1\pmod 7$). Ok (by $\pmod 6$),
$$
128^{128}= 2^{128} = 2\cdot2^{127} \pmod 3 = 2\cdot(-1)^{127}\pmod3 = 2\cdot2\pmod 3 = 4
$$
So,
$$
128^{128}\equiv 4\pmod 6
$$
and
$$
2^{128^{128}}\equiv 2^4\equiv 2\pmod 7
$$

Comment: Sorry, but no: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=128%5E(128%5E128)%20mod%207

Comment: @AnonymousPi, thanks

Answer (score 0):

$128 \equiv 2 \: mod \: 7$ like you said. Observe that $2^3\equiv 1\:mod\:7$ so that $2^k\equiv 2^{(k\:mod\:3)}\:mod\:7$. Thus, we need to compute $128^{128}\equiv 2^{128}\:mod\:3$. We now apply similar reasoning as before and observe that $2^2 \equiv 1 \: mod \: 3$ so that $2^k\equiv 2^{(k \: mod \: 2)} \: mod\: 3$. Since $128 \equiv 0 \: mod \:2$, then $2^{128}\equiv 1 \: mod \: 3$ and hence $128^{128^{128}}\equiv 2 \: mod \: 7$.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this problem is to reduce the base (as already attempted) as $128\equiv 2\pmod 7$.  Next we should reduce the exponent as much as possible to a "simpler" form:

$$128^{128}=(2^7)^{128}=2^{896}$$

which brings us to

$$2^{2^{896}}\pmod 7$$

Note that if we consider $2^{2^n}$, this is effectively squaring $2$ up to $n$ times.  Beginning with $2$, and letting $n=2$, we have $2^{2^2}=16\equiv 2\pmod 7$.  Since each square operation increases $n$ by $1$, an even number of square operations ($n=896$) would bring the original value down to $2\pmod 7$.  Thus the answer is correct, even though the modular reasoning is not.